# Excel 2013: How to sum values of a given range by omitting values given in a different range

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a WorkSheet with ProfitCenter, Cities and Amounts (called Data).
Then I have a second worksheet (same workbook) with exceptions of cities (named Exceptions)
Now I would like so sum all Profitcenter amounts in a range on Data-Worksheet except those where there cities are in a range of the exceptions-worksheet, but just for a specified report.

E.g.:
Data-Sheet:

```
A                 B          C
ProfitCenter  |   City   |   Amount
111               NY         1000
111               Paris      2000
222               Paris      3000
333               Rom        500
111               London     600
111               Helsinki   8000
```

Exception-Sheet

```
A        B
City  |  Reportname
Paris      A
Paris      B
London     A
```

To demonstrate a bit better what I want to do, here is the formula that doesn't work:

```
=sumproduct((Data!c:c)*(Data!A:A = "111")*(Data!B:B <> Exception!A:A)*(Exception!Reportname = "A"))
```

The Problem is, I have no fix cell value to use for comparison but two different ranges

Is there anybody who can help me solving that Problem?

Comment: Have you heard of/tried the SUMIF() function? https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Do you want to exclude only cities where the Reportname="A" in the second sheet?

Comment: Thx for your reply Tom. Yes, that is what I wanted to do.
Grade 'Eh' Bacon came up with a simple solution that works very well for me.

Comment: Thx to you too toby.
Yes I have tried SUMIF as well as SUMIFS. I have also tried that function as a Matrix function but it doesn't work. You cannot exclude values which are in a valuerange. At least I couldn't do it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach here seems best for your purposes. This will be by adding in a helper column in your Data sheet, which will define each cell's acceptability for summation.

In your Data sheet, on column D, add this formula (starting D2 and copied down), which does the following things: (1) Counts the number of times that the city in cell B2 on the Data sheet appears on the exception list, (2) excluding items where the Report name does NOT equal "A" [you will likely want some method of formulizing which report you care about, but I left it hardcoded for now], and (3) Checks to see whether the amount of matches on the exception list is equal to 0.

```
=COUNTIFS('Exceptions Sheet'!A:A,B2,'Exceptions Sheet'!B:B,"<>A")=0
```

Then simply have E1 sum the results, as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 I was going to use a similar approach (you could add extra conditions to SUMIFS if OP only wanted Profit centre 111)

Comment: @TomSharpe Good point - OP if you also want to filter by profit centre, simply change the last SUMIFS formula to include an additional range and criteria, like this: =SUMIFS(C:C,D:D,TRUE,A:A,"111")

Comment: what a simple and great stuff :-)
Many many thx for the idea(s) and for the great Explanation.

As I haven't found any formula or even idea on the Internet I was about writing my own formula in VBA. The above mentioned solution is much faster and easier to implement :-)

Comment: Thx Tom. I have also implemented your suggestion. I'm done now :-)